# In Ruby, how do you print out the URL params and Server environment variables?

Tags: ruby, cgi

In Ruby (running on a web server as a .cgi), how do you print out the URL params and Server environment variables, preferable without using any package?  (by the rawest form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the answer.  I also found something in the cgi package code that the variable

```
ENV
```

can be used to show all server variables.  It contains environment variables even if running ruby or irb in a shell or command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

These are passed to the Ruby interpreter itself via env variables; so you'll probably want to use the `cgi` package to get at them. E.g.:

```
require 'cgi'
print "Content-type: text/html\n"

print CGI.new.params;
```

For more, view the CGI documentation at http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/index.html

(BTW, mod-ruby that apache uses is flawed; you should try out Mongrel and Rack if you wanna go your own way as opposed to using Rails or Merb.)

Comment: For urls, you can access the params hash like so params[:param_name]